# Angular app.module.ts APP_INITIALIZER in providers section, a StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken Application Initializer

Tags: angular

I am trying to load initial configuration on file to load the following in app.module.ts

```
let myConfig = undefined;
export function initializeMyApp(nmyService : MyConfigService ) {
  return (): Promise<any> => nmyService.loadConfig()
      .toPromise()
      .then( config => {
        myConfig = config;
      })
}

imports: [MsalModule.forRoot({ clientID = myConfig.clientID etc... })

providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeMyApp,
      deps: [MyConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
]
```

When I startup the app, I get the following error

```
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken Application
> Initializer -> MyConfigService]:  main.ts:12 Failed to load resource:
> the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> [https://localhost:4200/site.json] Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1,
> Unexpected token. [https://localhost:4200/site.json]
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `site.json` in the `assets` folder and load it from `https://localhost:4200/assets/site.json`

Answer (score 3):

Check your `MyConfigService` service. Are you using `HttpClient` (ex. `Http`) dependency injection?
If so, then import `HttpClientModule` into your module (in imports section).